# How would I fix the alignment on this Table?

Tags: c, file, printf, alignment

I have coded this program in C that reads in a file and prints it out to a table that is aligned with vertical bars including a header and footprint. The file always has 3 columns but different amounts of rows. The columns will differ in the amount of characters in each. The problem that I am having is that the first file I read in aligns perfectly but when I read in others that are increased sizes in all of the columns it does not align. Is there a way to make it automatically align or do I have to do this manually every time?

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// constant to store the maximum size of the records that can be read from the file

enum
{
    // update MAX_SIZE to if the number of rows is more than 1000
    MAX_SIZE = 1024
};

// structure to store a record from the file
typedef struct
{
    char define[20];
    char octal[26];
    char description[1000];
} Record;

// string to store the header of the table
char header1[20], header2[20], header3[20];

// function to read the file and return the maximum length of the descriptions read from the file
int readFile(Record rec[], int *size)
{
    // open a file for input
    FILE *fp = fopen("input2.txt", "r");

    // check if the file opened successfully
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened!");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    int maxLength=0;
    // read the file
    // first we read the header of each column from the file
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s\n", header1, header2, header3);

    // now we read each record from the file
    while (fscanf(fp, "%19s ", rec[i].define) == 1) 
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%10s '%[^']'", rec[i].octal, rec[i].description);

        // find the length of the description and update the 'maxLength'
        if (strlen(rec[i].description) > maxLength) 
        {
            maxLength = strlen(rec[i].description);
        }

        // increment the value of i
        i++;
    }
    
    // close the input file
    fclose(fp);

    // update the number of records read from the file
    *size = i;

    return maxLength;
}

void printTable(Record rec[], int size, int WIDTH)
{
    char p='|';
    // print the header of the table
    for (int i = 0; i < 22 + WIDTH; i++)
        printf("-");

    printf("\n| %-7s %c %5s %c %-*s %c\n", header1, p, header2, p, WIDTH, header3,p);

    for (int i = 0; i < 22 + WIDTH; i++)
        printf("-");

    printf("\n");

    // print the table data
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("| %-7s | %5s | %-*s |\n", rec[i].define, rec[i].octal, WIDTH, rec[i].description);

    // print the footer
    for (int i = 0; i < 22 + WIDTH; i++)
        printf("-");

    printf("\n");
}

// driver function
int main()
{
    // create an array of recors of MAX_SIZE
    Record recs[MAX_SIZE];
    // initialize size of recs to zero
    int size = 0;

    // call readFile() function to read data from the file and update the size of recs
    int WIDTH = readFile(recs, &size);
    // call printTable() function to print the table in a well-formatted manner
    printTable(recs, size, WIDTH);

    return 0;
}
```

File:

```
#define octal description
O_APPEND 02000 'The file is opened in append mode.'
O_ASYNC 020000 'Enable signal-driven I/O.'
O_CLOEXEC 02000000 'Enable the close-on-exec flag for the new file descriptor.'
O_CREAT 0100 'If pathname does not exist, create it as a regular file.'
O_DIRECT 040000 'Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file.'
O_DIRECTORY 0200000 'If pathname is not a directory, cause the open to fail.'
O_DSYNC 010000 'Write operations will complete according to the requirements of synchronized I/O data integrity completion.'
O_EXCL 0200 'Ensure that this call creates the file.'
O_LARGEFILE 0 'Allow files whose sizes cannot be represented in an off_t to be opened.'
O_NOATIME 01000000 'Do not update the file last access time (st_atime in the inode) when the file is read(2).'
O_NOCTTY 0400 'If pathname refers to a terminal device it will not become the processs controlling terminal.'
O_NOFOLLOW 0400000 'If pathname is a symbolic link, then the open fails, with the error ELOOP.'
O_NONBLOCK 04000 'When possible, the file is opened in nonblocking mode.'
O_PATH 010000000 'Obtain a file descriptor that can be used perform operations that act purely at the file descriptor level.'
O_SYNC 04010000 'Write operations will complete according to the requirements of synchronized I/O file integrity completion.'
O_TMPFILE 020200000 'Create an unnamed temporary regular file.'
O_TRUNC 01000 'If the file already exists and is a regular file it will be truncated to length 0.'
```

What is currently being printed:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| #define | octal | description                                                                                                 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| O_APPEND | 02000 | The file is opened in append mode.                                                                          |
| O_ASYNC | 020000 | Enable signal-driven I/O.                                                                                   |
| O_CLOEXEC | 02000000 | Enable the close-on-exec flag for the new file descriptor.                                                  |
| O_CREAT |  0100 | If pathname does not exist, create it as a regular file.                                                    |
| O_DIRECT | 040000 | Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file.                                             |
| O_DIRECTORY | 0200000 | If pathname is not a directory, cause the open to fail.                                                     |
| O_DSYNC | 010000 | Write operations will complete according to the requirements of synchronized I/O data integrity completion. |
| O_EXCL  |  0200 | Ensure that this call creates the file.                                                                     |
| O_LARGEFILE |     0 | Allow files whose sizes cannot be represented in an off_t to be opened.                                     |
| O_NOATIME | 01000000 | Do not update the file last access time (st_atime in the inode) when the file is read(2).                   |
| O_NOCTTY |  0400 | If pathname refers to a terminal device it will not become the processs controlling terminal.               |
| O_NOFOLLOW | 0400000 | If pathname is a symbolic link, then the open fails, with the error ELOOP.                                  |
| O_NONBLOCK | 04000 | When possible, the file is opened in nonblocking mode.                                                      |
| O_PATH  | 010000000 | Obtain a file descriptor that can be used perform operations that act purely at the file descriptor level.  |
| O_SYNC  | 04010000 | Write operations will complete according to the requirements of synchronized I/O file integrity completion. |
| O_TMPFILE | 020200000 | Create an unnamed temporary regular file.                                                                   |
| O_TRUNC | 01000 | If the file already exists and is a regular file it will be truncated to length 0.                          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What it should look like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| #define     |     octal | description                                                                                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| O_APPEND    |     02000 | The file is opened in append mode.                                                                          |
| O_ASYNC     |    020000 | Enable signal-driven I/O.                                                                                   |
| O_CLOEXEC   |  02000000 | Enable the close-on-exec flag for the new file descriptor.                                                  |
| O_CREAT     |      0100 | If pathname does not exist, create it as a regular file.                                                    |
| O_DIRECT    |    040000 | Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file.                                             |
| O_DIRECTORY |   0200000 | If pathname is not a directory, cause the open to fail.                                                     |
| O_DSYNC     |    010000 | Write operations will complete according to the requirements of synchronized I/O data integrity completion. |
| O_EXCL      |      0200 | Ensure that this call creates the file.                                                                     |
| O_LARGEFILE |         0 | Allow files whose sizes cannot be represented in an off_t to be opened.                                     |
| O_NOATIME   |  01000000 | Do not update the file last access time (st_atime in the inode) when the file is read(2).                   |
| O_NOCTTY    |      0400 | If pathname refers to a terminal device it will not become the processs controlling terminal.               |
| O_NOFOLLOW  |   0400000 | If pathname is a symbolic link, then the open fails, with the error ELOOP.                                  |
| O_NONBLOCK  |     04000 | When possible, the file is opened in nonblocking mode.                                                      |
| O_PATH      | 010000000 | Obtain a file descriptor that can be used perform operations that act purely at the file descriptor level.  |
| O_SYNC      |  04010000 | Write operations will complete according to the requirements of synchronized I/O file integrity completion. |
| O_TMPFILE   | 020200000 | Create an unnamed temporary regular file.                                                                   |
| O_TRUNC     |     01000 | If the file already exists and is a regular file it will be truncated to length 0.                          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: "| %-12s | %9s | %-*s |\n"

Comment: I know how to manually do it. The problem is when the size changes I need it to format it automatically.

Comment: Sounds like you need to iterate over the contents of the table and calculate the maximum width of each column before you begin printing.

Comment: If I were to find this how can I put that number in front of the %s?

Comment: You already have code that finds the maximum length of the description field as it is read and code that adapts the printing of that field. What problem do you have extending that to the other two fields? They can be measured and formatted in the same way. The widths cannot be returned as a single number from `readFile`, but there are several alternatives available.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a contrived example of accomplishing the same goal.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ContrivedData {
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    char c[100];
};

int main(void) {
    struct ContrivedData cd1 = {"Hello", "world", "!"};
    struct ContrivedData cd2 = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
    struct ContrivedData cd[2];

    cd[0] = cd1;
    cd[1] = cd2;

    int cd_len = sizeof(cd) / sizeof(*cd);
    
    int max_a_len = 0;
    int max_b_len = 0;
    int max_c_len = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < cd_len; i++) {
        int a_len = strlen(cd[i].a);
        if (a_len > max_a_len) {
            max_a_len = a_len;
        }

        int b_len = strlen(cd[i].b);
        if (b_len > max_b_len) {
            max_b_len = b_len;
        }

        int c_len = strlen(cd[i].c);
        if (c_len > max_c_len) {
            max_c_len = c_len;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cd_len; i++) {
        printf("%-*s | %-*s | %-*s\n", 
               max_a_len, cd[i].a, 
               max_b_len, cd[i].b, 
               max_c_len, cd[i].c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Before printing the data I iterate over the array and calculate the maximum width of each field. Depending on the type of data, you may need to use some function other than `strlen`.

The result I get is:

```
% ./test2
Hello | world | !  
foo   | bar   | baz
```

If I change the data a bit, you can see that it still stays aligned.

```
% ./test2
Hello | world     | !  
foo   | barbarbar | baz
```

Answer (score 0):

Example function.

```
struct a 
{
    char *s ; int x; char *y;
} a[] = {
    {"Hello", 435342435432, "1"},
    {"dfgsfdgdgdfgdf", 5, "1fdsfsdfs"},
    {"Hellodfds", 43534, "sdffs"},
    {"H", 2435432, "1dfdsfdsfsdd"},
    {NULL,}
};


void print(struct a *data)
{
    int widths[3] = {0};
    struct a *wrk;
    size_t len;

    for(wrk = data; wrk -> s; wrk++)
    {
        if((len = strlen(wrk -> s)) > widths[0]) widths[0] = len;
        if((len = strlen(wrk -> y)) > widths[2]) widths[2] = len;
        if((len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", wrk -> x)) > widths[1]) widths[1] = len;
    }
    for(wrk = data; wrk -> s; wrk++)
    {
        printf("| %-*s | %*d | %*s |\n", widths[0], wrk -> s , widths[1], wrk -> x,  widths[2], wrk -> y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
| Hello          | 1550738536 |            1 |
| dfgsfdgdgdfgdf |          5 |    1fdsfsdfs |
| Hellodfds      |      43534 |        sdffs |
| H              |    2435432 | 1dfdsfdsfsdd |
```

Comment: It feels like this could use some more explanation, as opposed to just a block of code, and one with no comments at that.